# Usage of Tarantool and MySQL with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, tarantool

How can I use Tarantool in conjunction with Django and MySQL for caching (instead of i.e. Redis) and/or in the sense that all read transaction go to Tarantool (after insured MySQL replication) and all writes go into MySQL (preferred option) Would anyone have a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. Tarantool does not have a Django plugin. That means you have to introduce it first. By the way, tarantool has python 2.7[1](https://github.com/artembo/django-tarantool) and python 3.x[1](https://github.com/artembo/django-tarantool) libraries, so it may be useful for integration.

How it could be implemented? You have to use taranool's python library and also MySQL's python library for creating some Django / Python plugin.

Also. About MySQL replication. Tarantool has this feature, you can get codes from GH repo[2].

I'm not sure that Django's sample could be found.

Afterword. It's the pretty big task :)

> [1](https://github.com/artembo/django-tarantool) https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-python
>
> [2] https://github.com/tarantool/mysql-tarantool-replication

**UPD: February 2021:**

The Django-Tarantool Database Backend was introduced as **[django-tarantool](https://github.com/artembo/django-tarantool)** PyPi package and can be used for Django 1.10-3.1 versions.

```
pip install django-tarantool
```

Feel free to contribute to the package https://github.com/artembo/django-tarantool

Comment: Now we have it: https://pypi.org/project/django-tarantool/